# My Windows-7 taskbar is not responding

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7 taskbar not responding at all, to either left- or right-click of mouse (except for start menu ).  I cannot access any files or programs using this - eg moving between documents - neither do any of the icons on the bottom right respond.  Help!

Comment: Have you tried restarting the computer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

> Click Start
>
> Type: CMD, from the results, right click CMD
>
> Click 'Run as
>   Administrator'
>
> At the Command Prompt, type: sfc/scannow
>
> This will check for any integrity violations
>
> Restart your system
>
> 1. Insert the Windows 7 DVD
> 2. Restart your computer
> 3. When asked if you want to boot from your DVD drive, do so.
> 4. Choose your language, click Next.
> 5. Click 'Repair your computer'
> 6. Select operating system you want repair.